# Mozilla throwing Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

fellow developers!

I am sending a form data PUT request to my server to upload a photo. Here's the code:

```js
router.put("/profile-pic/new/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User not found...");
        let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send("Image could not be uploaded.");
            else if (files.profilePic) {
                if (files.profilePic.size > 1000000) {
                    return res.status(400).send("Image can not be larger than 1MB");
                }
                await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: user.id }, {
                    profilePic: {
                        data: fs.readFileSync(files.profilePic.path),
                        contentType: files.profilePic.type
                    }
                }, { useFindAndModify: false });
            }
        });
        res.send("Image uploaded successfully.");
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        next();
    }
});
```

So far I've been making this app using Chrome and on there all server requests work perfectly. I am uploading pictures and everything without a problem. I wanted to test out the app in Mozilla to check if I made any styling or layout errors only to find out that my Form Data was not being parsed correctly or at least not every time. When I try to upload a picture I get this error:

```js
(node:9388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\routes\user.js:64:45
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:104:9)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at IncomingForm._error (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:298:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:134:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
(node:9388) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9388) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried everything I could think of and nothing. So i just want to know what on Earth is going on here ... I have no unhandled promise rejections since I wrap every single router into a try-catch block and call an error handler if there's a rejected promise, so I have no idea what is going on. I'm also not setting any headers what so ever. And how is it working absolutely flawlessly when using Google Chrome and throwing an error in Mozilla. Also worth mentioning is that in Mozilla the picture uploads like 1 out of 10 times.

I guess what I want to know is, am I making some stupid mistake or is it just Mozilla being Mozilla?

Comment: `res.send("Image uploaded successfully.");` is called irrespective of whatever goes on in the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is that your final `res.send("Image uploaded successfully.");` is not in the `else` so it will be executed everytime, also when an error occurs and an response is already sent. Try to move the final `res.send()` in an else block under our `else if`.

Comment: This is probably not a problem with Mozilla, but in your Backend.

Comment: moved the res.send() inside the else if statement and it worked .. Thank you so much good sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Theoretically,**

`form.parse` is an asynchronous function. Maybe you are thinking that you are using `return` statement whenever sending a response to the client. But, `res.send("Image uploaded successfully.");` is getting executed even before completing `form.parse`. And then again from `form.parse` it tries to send a response to the client. That is when you get the error. It has nothing to do with the browser.